# Convergence of the Following Integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

Given $1<p<\infty,$ Mathematica gave me the following result:
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{(1-x^2)^{\frac{p}{2}}}dx=\frac{\Gamma\left(1-\frac{p}{2}\right)\sqrt{\pi}}{4\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{2}-\frac{p}{2}\right)}$$

as long as $p<2.$ Although I am quite interested how this was determined and would appreciate the solution in your response, I'm more interested in an estimate for this integral simply to determine that it is a convergent integral for $1<p<2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near zero, no problem.

Near $1$, the integrand
$$\frac {x^2}{(1+x)^{p/2}(1-x)^{p/2}} $$

is equivalent $(\sim ) $ to

$$\frac {1}{2^{p/2}}\frac {1}{(1-x)^{p/2}} .$$

thus, the integral converges if and only if
$$\frac {p}{2}<1$$
or $p <2$.